# Are Times New Roman, Helvetica, Arial safe in multilanguage web?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

Could somebody tell me if fonts TNR, Helvetica, Arial are safe in multilanguage website?

This website will be among others in English, Polish (polish diacritical signs), Greek (greek alphabet) and Russian (cyrillic). Will it be safe I just use for example:

```
font-family: Times New Roman, serif;
```

Should I bother about "special" Times New Roman, Helvetica, Arial for greek and russian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Times New Roman, Arial and Helvetica are featured within the [CSS2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#generic-font-families) and so can be considered safe to use. The `serif` at the end of your `font-family` declaration is the *generic family* and acts as a fall back. If the browser cannot render the specified font, it will fall back to a serif font.

As for whether they support Greek and Russian symbols: that's a different matter. You'll have to check this yourself (through sites like [fileformat](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/times_new_roman/list.htm)) to ensure they include the specific Unicode range.

Comment: I checked Times New Roman, Arial via fileformat and I can see that they have unicode chars for Greek and Cyrillic, but I'm not sure about Helvetica and I can't find good source to check that. Maybe some one knows good source?

Answer (score 1):

It will depent if you are using web fonts (@font-face) or just a font stack that will use the local system available fonts. If you are using the second option you can safely expect that the user have the appropiate version of the font to display his language. If you are using @font-face you will have to check wich unicode points have your version of the font.
This applies to any font family, not only Times, Helvetica & Arial.

Answer (score 0):

`serif` and `sans-serif` will be failsafe regarding that. Besides that, you need to look up if the fonts support Latin-2 (Russian, Polish) character set. For Greek this is the same but it’s not covered in Latin-1/2.

Best is to test yourself in these languages but there’s a pretty good chance these fonts support all your needs.